# Kashrut for the ice blended at coffee bean

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Is the coffee bean ice blended kosher, and if so according to who? I have tried to ask a rabbi but the answer has always been "I don't know."

Comment: Can you please provide some background? What is "coffee bean" and why would one think that a particular drink is or is not kosher?

Comment: Thank you. By Coffe Bean i mean the famous coffee shop. and I heard the hechsher went away but some rabbis told me it was kosher so I was confused

Comment: Are you speaking of the US chain? The Jerusalem store? Have you tried asking the store?

Answer (score 1):

The ice at [The Coffee Bean and Tea Leaf](https://www.coffee-bean.co.il/) is certified kosher under the Jerusalem Rabbinate, as are all of their food and drinks.

Comment: It's not mehadrin. I can't recall whether or not they use Chalav nochri but you can ask the mashgiach

Comment: does that hechsher also apply in la?

Comment: Even assuming the two places are part of a chain, each store requires its own mashgiach and teudat kashrut